# Importing module with a local name using importlib

Tags: python

Importing a module with a local name is easy with the `import` statement:

```
import numpy as np
```

I believe `np` here is referred to as the "local name" but I could be confused.

I can't work out how to use the `importlib` module to do the same thing. `importlib.import_module()` doesn't take an option for the local name as far as I can tell. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`import_module` just returns the module; it doesn't assign it to a name at all.  You can just assign it to a variable yourself:

```
short_name = importlib.import_module('really_long_module_name')
```

Comment: Wow, quick answers! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just use:

```
np = importlib.import_module('numpy')
```

`importlib.import_module` **returns** the module object it got for you, and doesn't, per se, bind any name in the current scope.

So, you do your own binding in the usual way -- by assignment! -- and it's entirely up to you how you want to name the variable you're assigning to:-)

Comment: Wow, quick answers! Thanks!