# How to do from module import * using importlib?

Tags: python, python-import

I would like to accomplish the same result as `from module import *` using importlib.

This question [Importing module with a local name using importlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28018694/importing-module-with-a-local-name-using-importlib) describes how to do `import module as mod`, which is related but not the same.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

To emulate `from X import *` you must import the module and then merge the appropriate names into the global namespace.

```
# get a handle on the module
mdl = importlib.import_module('X')

# is there an __all__?  if so respect it
if "__all__" in mdl.__dict__:
    names = mdl.__dict__["__all__"]
else:
    # otherwise we import all names that don't begin with _
    names = [x for x in mdl.__dict__ if not x.startswith("_")]

# now drag them in
globals().update({k: getattr(mdl, k) for k in names})
```

Comment: If X is a package, you also need to load any submodules listed in `__all__` but not yet imported. `__import__` will handle this for you if you specify `fromlist=['*']`; with importlib, I think you need to do it manually.

Comment: At least in python3 you need `globals().update(...)`